# How to use Scala's singleton-object types?

Tags: scala, types, object, singleton

I'm writing a class which serves as base class for a series of singleton objects. In each singleton objects, there will be vals representing certain properties, and I want to write a method which, for each singleton object, only accepts objects created by it.

So I have the following:

```
class Obj[M <: Maker]

class Maker {
  implicit val me: this.type = this
  def make[M <: Maker](implicit maker: M) = new Obj[M]
  def accept(obj: Obj[this.type]) = {...}
}
```

So far, so good. Then I want to declare one of these singleton objects:

```
object M extends Maker {
  val a = make
}
```

But then, if I try this:

```
M.accept(M.a)
```

then I get a compile-time error:

```
type mismatch; found : com.test.Obj[object com.test.M] required: com.test.Obj[com.test.M.type]
```

My questions:

1. What's the type `object com.test.M`, and how is it different from `com.test.M.type`?
2. How can I do this in a smarter way?

Comment: for point 2: there's always the possibility to make `Obj` a nested class of `Maker` and to remove the type parameter, but I don't want that, since I need to pass around Obj instances to objects outside the classes in my example and I need to filter on the type parameter.

Comment: Could you please provide a _compilable_ example? Something I can copy&paste into a REPL?

Comment: Great question: I ran into the same problem when implementing a HList and the type of HNil was inferred as **object HNil** and not **HNil.type**. Upgraded to 2.9 nightly build and all is fine now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get with the times, my good man! I fixed this over 24 hours ago.  Next I expect to see velociraptors chasing dodos, furiously cracking their buggy whips while looking up stock quotes on their pointcast screensavers.

The commit in question is: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/23622

```
// 1130.scala
class Obj[M <: Maker]

class Maker {
  implicit val me: this.type = this
  def make[M <: Maker](implicit maker: M) = new Obj[M]
  def accept(obj: Obj[this.type]) = ()
}

object M extends Maker {
  val a = make
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    M.accept(M.a)
  }
}

// too old
% /scala/inst/scala-2.9.0.r23619/bin/scalac ./1130.scala 
./1130.scala:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Obj[object M]
 required: Obj[M.type]
    M.accept(M.a)
               ^
one error found

// fresh enough
% /scala/inst/scala-2.9.0.r23624/bin/scalac ./1130.scala 
%
```

Comment: Nice! So I assume it was definitely a compiler bug rather than a problem with my mental representation of the types in play.

Comment: Well, nobody said it was a bug.  It was an undesirable behavior, but it was as specified.

Comment: Fair enough, but in this case, can you explain to me the difference between type `object M` and type `M.type`?

Comment: Not in a way that will make much sense outside of the implementation.  As of r23624 I don't know where you're even going to encounter "object M" anymore: it's not a type you can express, so if it's not inferred then it has become the type behind the curtain.

Answer (score 8):

Use `this.type` instead of `M`. This simplified example should work:

```
class Obj[M <: Maker]

class Maker {
  def make() = new Obj[this.type]
  def accept(obj: Obj[this.type]) = println(obj)
}

object M extends Maker

object N extends Maker

M.accept(M.make()) //works!
M.accept(N.make()) //error! type mismatch!
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But why doesn't my example work, what's wrong with my reasoning? What's exactly the difference between `object com.text.M` and `com.text.M.type`?

Answer (score 4):

Your first question, "What's the type `object com.test.M`, and how is it different from `com.test.M.type`?", still hasn't been answered.  I haven't found it documented in the spec, but it seems that the `object M` type is the internal type representing the class that is implicitly created when you define an object `M`.  Of course, `M` is the only instance of that class so one would expect the `object M` type to be equivalent to `M.type`, but the compiler apparently does not see it that way.

The problem you're running into, as [@retronym explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907727/how-to-correctly-type-annotate-this-hlist/3909655#3909655), is that the singleton type `M.type` is not inferred for the type parameter when you invoke your `make` method. This is for the same reason that `String` is inferred rather than `v.type` in the session below:

```
scala> val v = "asdf"                      
v: java.lang.String = asdf

scala> identity(v)
res0: java.lang.String  = asdf
```

where `identity` is defined as

```
def identity[T](v: T) = v
```

Comment: Makes sense. But it looks like extempore fixed this behavior in 2.9, so either `object M` is really `M.type` and there was a bug, or the type inference has slightly changed.

Comment: What also puzzled me if that when you write `val v = "string"`, v as type String, and when you write `val singleton = M`, then singleton has type `M.type` and not `object M`, so I expected my initial example to work. Glad it will in 2.9

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
class Obj[M <: Maker]

class Maker {
  implicit val me: this.type = this
  def make[M <: Maker](implicit maker: M) = new Obj[M]
  def accept(obj: Obj[this.type]) = ()
}

object M extends Maker {
  val a = make[M.type]
}

M.accept(M.a)
```

The secret "sauce" is using `make[M.type]` inside the singleton object.

@retronym deserves the credit for explaining this: [How to correctly type-annotate this HList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907727/how-to-correctly-type-annotate-this-hlist/3909655#3909655)

Comment: The implicit is redundant here: it will only ever force M to be this.type ... in which case we might as well use this.type directly, getting us Michel Krämer's solution.

Comment: Actually I'm trying hard to avoid the explicit `[M.type]` when calling `make` from `M`...

Comment: @Miles: I just assumed that he has trivialized his real case for the post but that in actual code he requires it